# Setting up a shell script to run at boot with sudo permission

Tags: boot, bluetooth, cron, raspbian-buster

I had issue with BLE Connection which would drop after certain time which I solved using solution from this post:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288978/how-to-configure-a-connection-interval-in-a-ble-connection

The issue is that the values are automatically reset after next boot.So I have been trying to setup a script that would automatically configure the values on startup.

The script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 16 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval
echo 17 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval
```

Now I have tried setting up using **Cron**:

```
@reboot sudo sh /home/pi/bleConn.sh
```

I have also tried adding it to `rc.local` as per other posts but the script is not executed using either method.
I have also configured for no-pass in visudo.
I want this values to be configured only once at startup(script requires sudo permissions)

Comment: This looks more like a Linux question than a Raspberry Pi specific question. You might have better luck on the Unix and Linux exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to extend the `bluetooth.service` with the commands. Edit the service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit bluetooth.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'echo 16 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval; echo 17 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval'
```

The service is executed with root rights by default so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Perfect!! This works as expected and settings are preserved after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure `cron` is enabled.

   ```
   systemctl status cron
   ```

   If it is not enabled, enable it.

   ```
   systemctl enable cron
   ```
2. Execute it from the global crontab.

   Create a file `/etc/cron.d/local` or `/etc/cron.d/ble`. The name doesn't matter, just the directory `/etc/cron.d`. Add a line

   ```
   @reboot   root   sh /home/pi/bleConn.sh
   ```

   If you make `/home/pi/bleConn.sh` executable (and you should, with `chmod a+x /home/pi/bleConn.sh`), then you can omit the `sh` after `root`. This causes the command to be executed as root, so no need for `sudo`.
3. Add logging to the script (second line):

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec > /tmp/bleConn.log 2>&1
   echo 16 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval
   echo 17 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval
   ```

   If this creates the file `/tmp/bleConn.log`, then look at the content for the problem. If the file is not created, then you know that the script is not executed.
4. Just a guess, maybe the script is executed before the modules are loaded the make the files available. You would see something like "/sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval does not exist". A simple fix is to wait long enough. Modify the cron line to sleep a few seconds, find a value that works for you.

   ```
   @reboot   root   sleep 30; /home/pi/bleConn.sh
   ```
5. The proper way is to find the correct entries for the udev configuration. But it requires finding the correct file and may lead to problems after updates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While the selected answer has fixed the issue, I am thankful for detailed information regarding cron.